# How to Position a table HTML?

Tags: html

I am trying to have the table lower and more to the right to were it originally is. How can i do this? What are the attributes? Thanks!

Comment: `margin`? More context please. A jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You would want to use CSS to achieve that.

say you have a table with the attribute id="my_table"

You would want to write the following in your css file

```
#my_table{
    margin-top:10px //moves your table 10pixels down
    margin-left:10px //moves your table 10pixels right
}
```

if you do not have a CSS file then you may just add `margin-top:10px, margin-left:10px` to the style attribute in your table element like so

```
<table style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;">
    ....
</table>
```

There are a lot of resources on the net describing CSS and HTML in detail

Comment: What is #my_table?

Answer (score 1):

As BalausC mentioned in a comment, you are probably looking for CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) not HTML attributes.

To position an element, a `<table>` in your case you want to use either padding or margins.

the difference between margins and paddings can be seen as the "box model":

[image: box model image]

Image from HTML Dog article on margins and padding http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/margins/.

I highly recommend the article above if you need to learn how to use CSS.

To move the table down and right I would use margins like so:

```
table{
    margin:25px 0 0 25px;
}
```

This is in shorthand so the margins are as follows:

```
margin: top right bottom left;
```